# jQuery $.then with arguments from previous functions

Tags: jquery

I have three ajax calls. The second should receive arguments from the results of the first one and the third one should receive arguments from the second one. Such as:

```
var getYears = function getYears() {return $.ajax({....});};
var getMonths = function(year)  {return $.ajax({...});};
var getDays = function(month, year) {return $.ajax({...})};
```

I am quite lost in how to chain these into a `$.when()`.

What I've done so far works fine, but I prefer doing it the `$.when()` way, as I will refer to the results later on in the code..

```
    function init() {
        var y, m, d;
        getYears().then(function (years) {
            var year = years.d[0];
            y = years.d;
            getMonths(year).then(function (months) {
                var month = months.d[0].MonthNo;
                m = months.d;
                getDays(month, year).then(function (days) {
                    d = days.d;
                }).done(function () {
                    return initialize = { years: y, months: m, days: d };
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

When I use when:

```
$.when(
    getYears(),
    getMonths(//here i need to refer the result of getYears),
    getDays(//here needs the result of getMonths).done(function()
    {// do something else})
);
```

Comment: something like [this](http://jsbin.com/eHuHudOp/1/edit?js)? (*posting as comment, because I'm not really sure if this is what you're trying to do*).

Comment: in jq 1.8+, you could just chain the `then`, something like that: `getYears().then(function(years){return getMonths(years.d[0])}).then(...)` Now i'm wondering, how you could pass `year` value to getDays()?!

Comment: I know, most of the examples I find does not require previous function results as paramters..

Comment: @Emin did you check the example I posted above? [Here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cz3uZzbZStvyVT3lmqWU) another one with real ajax calls.

Comment: @Yoshi, thank you for sparing your time to prepare that example however, I currently use similar functionality with $.then. $then ensures that one function completes before getting to another.. but, my question is how to use $.when, so that when all functions complete successfully, I run another function?

Comment: @Emin you'll not be able to pass the results of one function to the next using `when`, for `when` will not respect the order of the given functions. It's only use is to trigger one callback when all other functions are completed.

Comment: @Yoshi but can we use `then` within `when`?

Comment: @Emin What for? There issn't any real benefit by fixating on `when`. It's simply not the correct tool to use.

Comment: @Yoshi how do I ensure all three functions run succesfully if $.when is not meant for that?

Comment: @Emin That's not what I'm saying. `$.when` is not the correct tool to use when you want to chain async callbacks in a defined order while passing the results from the prior to the next. For `$.when` will trigger all callbacks immediately.

Comment: ok that makes sense now. Thanks for your efforts and time @Yoshi but I am already doing similar to what you recommend..

Answer (score 0):

`$.when()` takes in promises separated by commas (arrays wont work) then once all of those promises have resolved it passes them to the `then` function in the order specified by `$.when()`.This way you don't have to worry about which call back finishes first.

For example:

```
$.when(getyears,getmoths,getdays).then(function(year,month, day){
    console.log("today is: " + year + month + day);
});
```

In order to get those promises passed into when you need to use `$.deferred()` on your ajax calls so they return a promise.

Comment: getMonths() need year as parameter coming from getyears()

Comment: @A.Wolff ahh got ya. I had a feeling it was more complex than this

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/Chubyone/NtQKs/

the `init().done(function(day, month, year){ /*stuff */ });` especially?